# Sending keys to a specific handle in C#?

Tags: c#, window, mouse, sendkeys

I've been searching, and so far I've only found `SendKeys`, which works only for the active window. However, I don't want to force the window to become active. Does anyone know how I can send keystrokes to a specific window handle? I'm aiming, actually,  at a child window and SendKeys just does the parent window, which is why I need this specific functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468861%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP?

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I could send multiple keys (being held down at the same time) such as CTRL+R, etc.?

Comment: I think you can send a WM_KEYDOWN with VK_CONTROL, then a WM_KEYDOWN with VK_R, then a WM_KEYUP with VK_R, then WM_KEYUP with VK_CONTROL, but I'm not certain, been a while since I played around with using SendMessage for keyboard stuff.